# How to find last day of month?

Tags: dart

I am trying the new Google Dart language and I don't know how to get the last day of the current month?

This gives me current date:

```
var now = new DateTime.now();
```

Answer (score 123):

Providing a day value of zero for the next month gives you the previous month's last day

```
var date = new DateTime(2013,3,0);
print(date.day);  // 28 for February
```

Comment: Is this an actual legitimate use of DateTime? If so, might we want to update the documentation for DateTime?

Comment: Neat. I take it that this stays as-is in the future?

Comment: Yes. this is guaranteed behavior.

Comment: @FlorianLoitsch same is for 
new DateTime(2016,0,1) (1 Dec 2015).
 Is it guaranteed as well ?

Comment: `print(new DateTime(2022,4,0).day);` I got 31.

Answer (score 46):

If you want to get the last date of the current month, you need to refer to the 0th day of the next month

Try this in an easy way:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
int lastday = DateTime(now.year, now.month + 1, 0).day;
```

Comment: What if you want to know the full date and not just the day in the month?

Comment: iterable from 1 to lastDate

Comment: what if month is december?

Answer (score 25):

Here's one way to find it:

```dart
var now = new DateTime.now();

// Find the last day of the month.
var beginningNextMonth = (now.month < 12) ? new DateTime(now.year, now.month + 1, 1) : new DateTime(now.year + 1, 1, 1);
var lastDay = beginningNextMonth.subtract(new Duration(days: 1)).day;

print(lastDay); // 28 for February
```

I have the current date, so I construct the first day of the next month, and then subtract one day out of it. I'm also taking the change of the year into account.

**Update:** Here's a little bit shorter code for the same thing, but inspired by Chris's zero-trick:

```dart
var now = new DateTime.now();

// Find the last day of the month.
var lastDayDateTime = (now.month < 12) ? new DateTime(now.year, now.month + 1, 0) : new DateTime(now.year + 1, 1, 0);

print(lastDayDateTime.day); // 28 for February
```

It has the additional check/code, in case you want to do this programmatically (e.g. you have a specific month as an integer).

Comment: Note that subtracting 1 day (= 24 hours) wouldn't work if you are exactly on the date where daylight-savings is turned off. In this case it probably doesn't matter since the switch-days are never (?) on the last day of a month.

Comment: You are right. And there are switch-days on the last day of a month.

Answer (score 9):

Here's an extension that might help. (Ref. from Kai's and Chris's answers.)

```
extension DateTimeExtension on DateTime {

  DateTime get firstDayOfWeek => subtract(Duration(days: weekday - 1));

  DateTime get lastDayOfWeek =>
      add(Duration(days: DateTime.daysPerWeek - weekday));

  DateTime get lastDayOfMonth =>
      month < 12 ? DateTime(year, month + 1, 0) : DateTime(year + 1, 1, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way is using [Jiffy](https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy#-readme-tab-). It has the [endOf](https://github.com/jama5262/jiffy/tree/v3.0.1/doc#end-of-time) method that makes easy to get the last moment of several units, in this case the month:

```dart
Jiffy.now().endOf(Unit.month);

// Or if you have an existing Datetime
Datetime dt = DateTime.now();
Jiffy.parseFromDateTime(dt).endOf(Unit.month);
```

Comment: for some reason this returns the first day of next month

Answer (score 2):

First, you can do this at build time with the `DateTime` class. That works well if you have a specific number of months or years that you want to evaluate to get the last date.

```
DateTime first = DateTime(month.value.year, month.value.month, 1);
```

That method always gets the first date of month.

After this, try modified date by adding 1 month so that it will get the first date in next month. Then add -1 day so you will get the last day of month.

```
DateTime end = Jiffy(first).add(months: 1, days: -1).dateTime;
```

***Note:*** Try using Jiffy because it makes it easy to modify the date object.

Answer (score 1):

This works well for me

```
DateUtils.getDaysInMonth(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month,)
```

[DateUtils.getDaysInMonth documentation here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DateUtils/getDaysInMonth.html)

Answer (score 0):

*While all this answers are correct & do give you the last **DAY** of the month :*

like so : `year-month-lastDay 00:00:00.000` -> *beginning of the last day of the month*

---

You might need the last bound / **DateTime** of the month :

like so : `year-month-lastDay 23:59:59.999` -> *end of the last day of the month*

Here is how to get the two bounds within a month with the help of an `extension on DateTime` :

```dart
extension MonthsBounds on DateTime {

  DateTime get lastMillisecondOfMonth =>
      month < 12 ? DateTime(year, month + 1, 1, 00, 00, 00, -1) : DateTime(year + 1, 1, 1, 00, 00, 00, -1);
  
  DateTime get firstMillisecondOfMonth => DateTime(year, month, 1);
}
```

```dart
  print('${DateTime(2022, 12, 14).lastMillisecondOfMonth}'); // 2022-12-31 23:59:59.999
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2023, 12, 1);

var lastDayDateTime = new DateTime(dt.year, dt.month + 1, 0);

print(lastDayDateTime.toString()); // 2023-12-31


//obs:
print(DateTime(2023, 13, 1).toString()); // '2024-01-01'    :~) 
print(DateTime(2023, 14, 1).toString()); // '2024-02-01'    :~)
```